# Passing JVM opts to maven plugin

Tags: maven-plugin

I know that plugins like surefire have an "argLine" configuration parameter which they pass along to the JVM where the specific goals for the plugin is run. As I understand, by default, maven plugins are forked and run in a separate JVM (please correct me if I am wrong).
I am trying to figure out how to pass on VM arguments to a maven plugin [jibx](https://github.com/jibx/maven-plugin/tree/master/jibx-maven-plugin), but don't know if there is an easier/declarative way (or via a Util class) that I can configure it to do this. In surefire, there are utility classes in booterclient that seem to be handling this, but the functionality seems to be universal across plugins, right? Hence wondering if there might be some support from Mojo/Plexus to add this easily without writing a bunch of plumbing code. Again, please correct me if my understanding is incorrect

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The actual Maven plugin classes are run in the same JVM as Maven.

Where a Maven plugin is wrapping a separate tool, it depends on how the Maven plugin was written whether it forks a process or not.

For example the Cobertura Maven Plugin forks a process to do the Cobertura things. There is no technical reason for this fork, in the case of Cobertura the forking of the JVM is to work around the GPL licensing of the Cobertura Tool itself.

As you noticed the Surefire plugin usually forks a process for running the unit tests. It does not technically need to fork (see `forkMode=never`) however, there are good reasons due to the poor isolation of some parts of the JVM that require forking, e.g. System properties being global.

Looking at the plugin in your question [you can see that it is just invoking the JIBX's main method directly](https://github.com/jibx/maven-plugin/blob/master/jibx-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/jibx/maven/AbstractJibx2WsdlMojo.java#L222). In other words it is not forking the JVM at all. If there are JVM options that you want, you will need to use the `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable to specify them (with the side-effect that they are global for Maven, and if you forget to specify them, then things will not work as you expect)

I think to fix this you should really suggest a patch to the plugin that forks and accepts JVM options for the forked JVM